# what would happened if I changed the C++ Dynamic Shared Library on Linux while my executable program using on it

Tags: c++, linux, coredump, dlopen, inode

I have a C++ dynamic shared library `abc.so` on Linux and my executable program dynamic loading it with `dlopen`, and then cover `abc.so` with a new version using `rm + cp` in case of change inode of the using `abc.so`, but there are also coredump sometimes, I realize that this may relate to the delay-loaded on dynamic shared library, but I can't confirm it, anybody could help me to figure out why? thanks very much!

Comment: POSIX systems (like Linux) don't really overwrite files that are open by some application. Instead a new file is created on disk which will be found by subsequent open calls. The old file will still exist until the last application referencing the file have "closed" it.

Comment: Probably nothing until you restart your program. Ubuntu is now shipping hot-patching of kernels to avoid machine restarts, but I am not aware of hot-patching being applied to userland. Also see [Kernel Livepatch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch) on the Ubuntu wiki. Microsoft has had hot patching for years for both kernel and user libraries. Also see the [Microsoft Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the possibility to investigate it myself, this becomes speculative but using:

```
rm abc.so
cp new_version.so abc.so
```

has no effect on programs that has already loaded `abc.so`. For programs linked with `abc.so` (or using `dlopen` to load it) it will present a problem if they are started (or uses `dlopen`) while the file is removed or it's being copied into place. A core dump could very well be the result.

A better way to replace your `abc.so`:

```
copy new_version.so to the same filesystem as abc.so (like the same directory)
mv new_version.so abc.so
```

This assures that there is always a complete version of `abc.so` where it's expected to be. Any program needing it will either get the old version *or* the new version - and there's nothing in between.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that the result becomes speculative if I replace the abc.so with new_version.so (even use mv) when my executable program dlopen the abc.so with RTLD_LAZY, especially the ABI of abc.so has been changed

Comment: @W.Terry I'm surprised that `RTLD_LAZY` has any effect on this. What if you start your program, let it `dlopen(RTLD_LAZY...)` and then remove `abc.so` without replacing it at all? Will it crash when resolving symbols? If you change the interface you need to recompile the applications using `abc.so` so I hope you just did that as a test?

Comment: Thanks @Ted Lyngmo, I have retest all cases, and the results prove that your conclusion is right.